# Use the definition of continuity to prove a function is defined at every nonnegative real number

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Use the definition of continuity to prove that the function f defined by f(x) = (x)^(½) is continuous at every nonnegative real number.

Our definition of continuity: Let I be an interval, let f:I-R, and let c(element of)I. The function f is continuous at c if for each (epsilon)>0 there exists (delta)>0 such that |f(x)-f(c)| < (epsilon) for all x (element of) I that satisfy |x-c|<(delta). The function f is continuous on I if f is continuous at each point of I.

I'm not sure how to the nonnegative real number comes into play here in terms of proving the continuity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Continuity at $c=0$ is continuity from the right, so one wants to show given $\varepsilon$ there is $\delta$ for which $0 \le x < \delta$ implies $0 \le \sqrt{x} < \varepsilon$. The natural choice here is $\delta=\varepsilon^2.$

Otherwise $c>0$ and we initially restrict to $\delta<c/2$ (and throw that in at the end via the usual "min" definition.) From this assumption we have $c/2<x<3c/2$ and so
$$\sqrt{c/2}<\sqrt{x}<\sqrt{3c/2}.$$

Now we consider that
$$|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{c}|=\frac{|x-c|}{\sqrt{x}+\sqrt{c}}. \tag{1}$$
Given our bounds for $\sqrt{x}$ the right side of $(1)$ is at most $|x-c|/(\sqrt{c/2}+\sqrt{c}),$ so that if we finally define $\delta$ as the minimum of the two numbers $c/2$ and $\varepsilon \cdot (\sqrt{c/2}+\sqrt{c})$ we'll have $|x-c|<\delta$ implies $|\sqrt{x}-\sqrt{c}|<\varepsilon.$

Answer (score 0):

We know $x\geq0$ therefore if we want $\lim_{x \to \infty} \exp(-x) = 0$ we have that for any $\epsilon$ then there exists a delta (which we will allready take such that $\delta\leq x_0$. Then we need $\epsilon \geq \sqrt x_0 - \sqrt{x_0\pm\delta} \iff \epsilon-\sqrt x_0\geq - \sqrt {x_0\pm \delta}$ but we took $\delta$ so that the part inside the square is positive. Therefore this happens if and only if $\epsilon^2+x_0^2-2\epsilon x_0-x_0\geq\delta$.

Answer (score 0):

We let ϵ > 0 be given to us and let cϵℝ+. Then we must show for each ϵ > 0 there is a corresponding d > 0 such that |f(x) - f(c)| < ϵ for all xϵℝ+ that satisfy |x - c| < d. We take d = ϵ^2.  That is, |x - c| < ϵ^2 => (|x -c|)^(½) < ϵ => |x^(½) - c^(½)| < ϵ, since x,cϵℝ+ . Thus, we have |f(x) - f(c)| < ϵ for all nonnegative real numbers, as desired.

Answer (score -1):

The function g : x->x is continuous, the function h : x->x^(1/2) is also continuous, so the function f is also continuous, because it is equal to h(g(x)) which is continuous as a composed of two continuous function.

Comment: The OP asks to prove that the function you call $h$ is continuous. This doesn't prove that in any way, shape or form.

Comment: It seems any function is a composition of the identity function with itself. Marvelous!